# How does bottleneck layer reduce computations without compromising with performance?

Tags: deep-learning, autoencoder, inception

I was reading an article explaining the google's inception model . There it was mentioned , that to reduce the number of computations , we use a bottleneck layer. But I was surprised , if the model was somehow compromising the performance , as the bottleneck layer introduces a layer that has very less number of features. From what I understand , as we decrease the number of features (dimensions) , there is a loss of information .

Also when I read a little bit more , I got to know that it has to do something with encoders, but I am unable to connect the dots.

So how does the bottleneck layer works exactly ?